# IsoWeekYear within DAX

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, powerquery

Does anyway have a way of creating IsoWeekYear within DAX?

I use the following within excel to create, however am struggling to get this working within PowerBI

=YEAR(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,1)-MOD((DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,1)-2),7)+(7*IF(MOD((DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+4),1,1)-2),7)>3,1,0))+7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the DAX [WEEKNUM](https://dax.guide/weeknum/) function. It has an optional parameter for the ISO 8601 week. Option 21 will return the ISO Week

```
ISO Week Number = WEEKNUM([DateColumn], 21)
```

To get the ISO Year, you'll need a calendar week and year column as well.

```
Calendar Week = WEEKNUM([DateColumn])
Year = YEAR([DateColumn])

Year Week = IF([ISO Week Number]<5 && [Calendar Week] > 50,
     [Year]+1,
     IF([ISO Week Number] >50 && [Calendar Week]<5,
          [Year]-1,
          [Year]))
```

You can do this all in one column, rather that split them out in this example and concat, year and week number to be 202101, or keep them separate, to whatever type you need.

[image: Full example of weeknum]

Comment: Thanks for you support. Im not sure this is quite what I meant. For example 31-Dec-2019, needs to be reported as the year 2020. The normal =YEAR() formula doesn’t have an ISO feature. It is more which year does the week belong too based on the ISO standards.

*Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Updated, I saved the answer by accident before i finished

Comment: Im adding a table using the add columns method, is there anyway I could rewrite this to work within? 

ADDCOLUMNS (
CALENDAR (DATE(2017,1,1), DATE(2021,12,31)),
"DateAsInteger", FORMAT ( [Date], "YYYYMMDD" ),
"Year", YEAR ( [Date]),
"Monthnumber", FORMAT ( [Date], "MM" ))

Comment: Updated: I managed to get it working within the ADDCOLUMNS function when creating a table.

"IsoWeekYear", IF(WEEKNUM([Date], 21)<5 && WEEKNUM([Date]) > 50,
     YEAR ( [Date])+1,
     IF(WEEKNUM([Date], 21) >50 && WEEKNUM([Date])<5,
          YEAR ( [Date])-1,
          YEAR ( [Date]))))

Comment: @tg00222 nice one!